# Using same partial but with different variable for loop Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use the same partial, but changing the main variable of the loop inside the partial so that the layout is the same, but different results show in each tab. I thought I could make this happen using locals, but I tried it with no luck. Any ideas?

```
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="campaigns-active-tab">
    <%= render partial: 'campaigns_list' %>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="campaigns-inactive-tab">
    <%= render partial: 'campaigns_list' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@active_campaigns = @campaigns.where(status: 1).order(created_at: :desc)
@inactive_campaigns = @campaigns.where(status: 2).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Partial:

Here, the variable should change from active to inactive campaigns:

```
  <% @campaigns.each do |campaign| %>
      <tr scope="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
```

Comment: "I thought I could make this happen with locals" - what is it that you actually tried? Did you read the guides? Its not that complicated. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought I could make this happen with locals

Yes you can; however, the code you provided does not use locals.

Local usage would be:

`<%= render partial: 'campaigns_list', locals: { campaigns: @active_campaigns } %>`

And you can thus loop through `campaigns` within the partial.

[Docs for locals](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)